# SDK. Мгновенное отображение графики внутри onClick(View v)

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Как заставить графику меняться сразу, вместе с звуком?

Выполняемый код:

```
.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   //и вот здесь есть пару действий с программной задержкой
   sp.play(soundIdShoot, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
   .setBackground(destroy_ship);
                SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    sp.play(soundIdShoot, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    .setBackground(destroy_ship);
);}
}
```

Звуки отрабатывают сразу(звук, 2 секунды задержки, звук), а вот все графические действия отображаются после выполнения  `onClick`.

Comment: Может проблема в том, что картинка у вас оба раза одна и та же?..

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
            img.setBackground(destroy_ship_1);
            sp.play(soundIdShoot, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1);
            Handler h = new Handler();
            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    img.setBackground(destroy_ship_2);
                    sp.play(soundIdShoot, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1);
                }
            }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что Вы сначала задаете потоку заснуть, а потом меняете.
Вынесите проигрывание звука в отдельный поток. Схематично:

```
onClick(View v) {
    .setBackground(destroy_ship);
    (Thread/AsyncTask/Handler ... {
        Пыщ-пыщ звук
    })
)
```